# trigger click when I click on a circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to click on a circle and receive the element to which I clicked. But I am unable to execute this trigger. How can i fix it?

https://plnkr.co/edit/keLfbZ13wz8h9nMHp8pN?p=preview

```
var coordenadas=map.latLngToLayerPoint([coordinates[0].lat,coordinates[0].long]);
svg.append('circle').attr("cx",coordenadas.x)
.attr("cy", coordenadas.y)
.attr("r", 30)
.style("fill",'red')
.attr("class",'circulo_mapa')
.on("click", function(element){
   console.log('this is the element', element);
   alert("click")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [forked your plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/1RxNciGG74x7cGtjhb1r?p=preview) to add two things:

- make the circle react intercept pointer events
- log `this` instead of `element` in the click callback (which is what you will likely want to select)

Here is the upadted method:

```
var coordenadas = map.latLngToLayerPoint([coordinates[0].lat,coordinates[0].long]);

//add circle on map
        var coordenadas=map.latLngToLayerPoint([coordinates[0].lat,coordinates[0].long]);
        svg.selectAll('circle').data(new Array(3))
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr("cx",function(d,i){return coordenadas.x+i*10})
            .attr("cy", function(d,i){return coordenadas.y+i*20})
            .attr("r", 30)
            .style("fill",'red')
            .style('stroke', 'black')
            .style('pointer-events', 'all')
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .attr("class",'circulo_mapa')
            .on("click", function(d,i){
              console.log('this is the element', this);
              alert("click on " + i)
            })
```

Comment: one last question. How do I know what the index of the element to which I click? For example I have 3 circles. I clicked on the second circle. How can I make it return a 1?

Comment: I see only one in the plunk, but when bound to data, the callback takes two arguments (i.e. `function(d,i)`). The first is the bound data, the second is the index

Comment: Suppose I have 3 circles. I click on one of them. How do I get the index of the circle? There are 3 circles, but if for example I click on the third, I need to receive the number 2. How can I do it ?. you understand me?

Comment: Yes, I get it. If you want to rely on d3 to help you, you need to append the circles using the enter-update-delete pattern. That way, you can use `.on('click', function (d,i))`, where i corresponds to the index if the circle.

Comment: I have not made myself understood. I did this so you can understand me https://plnkr.co/edit/MYqQwMLFOaLB99XJbx3u?p=preview. But first look at this picture. http://i.imgur.com/ydZq6Fa.jpg there are 3 circles. When I click on a circle I want to know the index that the circle occupies in the DOM. For example if I click on the third circle I need to get a 2. can you explain how to do it please? (There are 3 circles that overlap, but by logic when clicking on a circle is clicking on the last)

Comment: ...or my explanation was not clear :-). I updated my answer and the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZrsHrPx8Vx41EmDtMxBs?p=preview) so that you can see the result. I moved the circles a bit so that they don't overlap, and displayed the index of the clicked circle in the alert.

Comment: You're most welcome, that's why stackoverflow exists :-)